# How to monitor my connection continuity within 24 hours

Tags: home-networking, internet-connection, monitoring, isp, network-monitoring

I have a bad ISP, and my internet cuts off for like 10 seconds every 2 hours or so and return.
According to my ISP it's fixed, but they've been saying that for weeks now.

My question is, is there a way to monitor if my internet is being cut off for a duration of 24 hours?

I tried ping, but it's hardly reliable and I will have to set on front of the pc to keep track.

Is there a software that can monitor the continuity of my internet connection for 24 hours straight?

Comment: Depending on the brand/firmware most routers and modems have built-in capabilities to log your connection status. Have you checked them?

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ, thank you for your response, I have a DLINK DSL-2740U, however the only report available is a general statistics report, that shows the amount of packets sent and received, but nothing to indicate if the the internet connection is being lost, I was wondering if there's a software that does the same job as the pinging function but with detailed reports, That I can know if at some point the destination was unreachable, or something along those lines.

Comment: Wireshark might fit the bill?

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned using `ping`, and you're absolutely right, only you don't need to stare at your screen and wait for connectivity issues. Send the output of `ping` to a file, and `Ctrl+C` to stop pinging when you feel enough time has passed.

`ping 8.8.8.8 > log.txt`

8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS. The ping command will write to `log.txt` in whatever your current working directory is.

Alternatively, here is a quick-and-dirty way to incorporate time stamps with each ping using Powershell, assuming you're using a version of Windows with PowerShell. When you `break` and decide to run this again later, it will append to your log file.

```powershell
$hostToPing = '8.8.8.8'
$logPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\temp\pinglog.txt"
$alwaysTrue = 1

while($alwaysTrue -eq "1")
{
    # refresh the timestamp before each ping attempt
    $theTime = Get-Date -format g

    # refresh the ping variable
    $result = ping $hostToPing -n 1

    if ($result -like '*reply*')
    {
        Write-Output "$theTime - pass - connection to $hostToPing is up" | Out-File $logPath -append
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "$theTime - fail - connection to $hostToPing is down" | Out-File $logPath -append
    }

    Sleep 1
    echo ' '
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but if you are going to use Powershell, why not use `Test-Connection` which do a ping with the default options, and the output can be used directly. ie `if (Test-Connection remotehost -Count 1) { "pass"} else { "fail" } `.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have been doing to track the continuity of 2 computers on campus.  This is all done in a .bat file without powershell.

The first 3 lines just set the prompt so I'm not looking a the long path to the file.  Then I overwrite the file pingtest.txt in the same folder as the .bat (`.\pingtest.txt`, `.\` means current folder).  The `ping -n 1` sends 1 ping and `>>` appends the output to the bottom of the file as well as the current time `%time%`.  The `timeout /t 5 > nul` is a wait in seconds, then it restarts.

When you have been watching for as long as you want.  Close the cmd window and search the .txt for 100 or timed and it will show you all pings that had 100% loss or timed out.

```cmd
@echo off
prompt timer$F > nul
@echo on

echo Tracking starts at %time% > .\pingtest.txt

@echo off 

:start

ping -n 1 address1 >> .\pingtest.txt
echo %time% >> .\pingtest.txt

ping -n 1 address2 >> .\pingtest.txt
echo %time% >> .\pingtest.txt

timeout /t 5 > nul

goto :start
```

Answer (score 0):

I was reading an [article](http://arstechnica.com/business/2016/02/comcast-customer-made-bot-that-tweets-at-comcast-when-internet-is-slow/) on [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) the other day where they were lambasting Comcast for being a crappy ISP.  Someone came up with a Raspberry Pi that tweets out their speed if it's substantially less than advertised.

In the commentary of the article, someone mentioned [SmokePing](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) ([DSL Reports has an FAQ too](https://www.dslreports.com/faq/13843)).  I will be looking into this software, and it sounds like you might want to as well.  It looks like it's a cloud service reaching out to your network, but [based on the comment](http://arstechnica.com/business/2016/02/comcast-customer-made-bot-that-tweets-at-comcast-when-internet-is-slow/?comments=1&post=30562639#comment-30562639), I thought it was something you could set up locally to see outbound metrics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add to root's answer, you need to do `ping -t 8.8.8.8 > log.txt`, otherwise it will only ping four times and then stop. `-t` will make it ping continuously.

More info: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping